# Como distribuir palavras em uma área de tamanho fixo?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, posicionamento

Tenho uma lista de palavras e preciso distribuí-las em uma área de dimensões fixas, de modo que pareça que tenham sido dispostas aleatoriamente nesse espaço. Porém, preciso garantir que as palavras não encavalem, e que não haja grandes "buracos" em branco na área. O resultado deve ser visualmente harmonioso.

Com um [CSS simples](http://jsfiddle.net/3yQEG/), consigo um resultado preso demais ao grid:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto o que estou buscando é algo parecido com isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe algum algoritmo clássico que me permita distribuir as palavras no espaço, com posicionamento absoluto, obtendo um resultado próximo ao que estou buscando?

Comment: já tentou com texto justificado? não ficou bom?

Comment: @SparK Ainda fica "certinho" demais - http://jsfiddle.net/sRe9k/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma solução simples é aplicar um deslocamento aleatório menor que a margem:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
function rand() {
    return getRandomInt(-20, 20);
}

$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'left': rand() + 'px',
        'top': rand() + 'px',
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/T9AAu/)

Um solução mais completa é calcular e somar a largura dos elementos, distribuindo-os em linhas conforme a média das larguras. Depois, em cada linha, distribui-se os elementos como se fosse uma tabela independente das demais linhas.

Não sei se consigo explicar bem o algoritmo, então vou postar o código:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
function rand(n) {
    return getRandomInt(-n, n);
}

//calcula tamanhos dos itens para distribuição
var itens = [];
var larguraTotal = 0;
$('li').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    larguraTotal += $this.width();
    itens.push({
        item: $this,
        width: $this.width(),
        height: $this.height()
    });
});

//define a quantidade de linhas
var linhas = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(itens.length));
var larguraMedia = larguraTotal / linhas;

//faz a distribuição dos elementos nas linhas de uma grid imaginária
var grid = [ [] ];
grid[0].largura = 0;
for (var i = 0, larguraConsumida = 0, linha = 0, coluna = 0, proximaQuebra = larguraMedia; i < itens.length; i++) {
    var item = itens[i];

    //quebra a linha, caso mais da metade do elemento ultrapasse a média
    if (larguraConsumida + item.width / 2 > proximaQuebra) {
        linha++;
        grid[linha] = [];
        grid[linha].largura = 0;
        coluna = 0;
        larguraLinha = 0;
        proximaQuebra = larguraMedia * (linha + 1);
    } else {
        coluna++;
    }
    //armazena a largura 
    grid[linha].largura += item.width;
    larguraConsumida += item.width;
    grid[linha].push(item);

}

//coloca os elementos na posição final (uma célula do container)
var container = $('ul');
//a largura da célula (local onde o item deve ser inserido)
var larguraCelula = container.height() / grid.length;
for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

    var linha = grid[i];
    //altura da célula (local onde o item deve ser inserido)
    var alturaCelula = container.width() / linha.length;
    //calcula o espaço horizontal que tem para randomizar, isto é, o espaço em branco até onde não enconsta no próximo elemento
    //deve dividir por 2 pela possibilidade do outro elemento também poder se aproximar, mas multiplicando por 0.4 garante que não vão encostar um no outro
    var espacoLivreEntreElementos = (container.width() - linha.largura) / linha.length * 0.4;
    //itera sobre os itens da linha    
    for (var j = 0; j < linha.length; j++) {

        var item = linha[j];
        //calcula o espaço vertical em branco para randomizar, usando o mesmo princípio anterior
        var espacoLivreVertical = (larguraCelula - item.height) * 0.4;
        item.item.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            //posiciona o item horizontalmente no meia da célula e randomiza no espaço que sobra
            left: (j + 0.5) * alturaCelula
                - item.width / 2 
                + rand(espacoLivreEntreElementos) + 'px',
            //posiciona o item verticalmente no meia da célula e randomiza no espaço que sobra
            top: (i + 0.5) * larguraCelula
                - item.height / 2 
                + rand(espacoLivreVertical) + 'px'
        });
    }
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/3u8Ps/)

---

## Resultado aleatório 1

[image: Resultado aletório 1]

---

## Resultado aleatório 2

[image: Resultado aleatório 2]

Comment: A solução mais completa tende a dar resultados melhores que a primeira. Vou estudar o código com calma e comparar com o do mgibsonbr, pelo que entendi é uma abordagem parecida. Obrigado!

Comment: @bfavaretto Pelo que entendi a principal diferença é que a minha solução mantém a ordem inicial. Mas sinceramente não analisei a dele muito a fundo ainda. Na verdade demorei muito pra responder pq estou meio sem tempo hoje. ;)

Answer (score 8):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é descobrir a altura e largura na tela de cada palavra. [Essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118251/520779) mostra um possível caminho (criar um `div` com a palavra e medir seus `clientWidth` e `clientHeight`).

```
var palavras = [];
var larguraTotal = 0;
var alturaMaxima = 0;
$('li').each(function() {
    palavras.push({
        elemento:this,
        largura:this.clientWidth,
        altura:this.clientHeight
    });
    larguraTotal += this.clientWidth;
    alturaMaxima = Math.max(alturaMaxima, this.clientHeight);
});
```

Feito isso, você precisa descobrir a forma mais "harmoniosa" de se distribuir suas palavras na tela (i.e. não deixá-las "apertadas" na horizontal e "folgadas" na vertical, ou vice-versa). Uma maneira - não necessariamente a melhor - seria:

```
var linhas = 0;
do {
    linhas++;
    var horizontal = larguraTotal / linhas / larguraConteiner;
    var vertical = linhas * alturaMaxima / alturaConteiner;
} while ( vertical < horizontal*0.8 ); // Esse 0.8 é uma "folga"
```

Agora é [problema da mochila](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila)! Bom, quase... Você precisa escolher, para cada linha, um conjunto de palavras que se aproxime da largura desejada (`larguraConteiner * horizontal`). Sugiro começar pelas maiores, pois fica mais fácil encaixar as menores depois.

```
var distribuicao = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < linhas ; i++ )
    distribuicao.push({ palavras:[], larguraTotal:0 });
function minima() {
    var min = 0;
    for ( var i = 1 ; i < distribuicao.length ; i++ )
        if ( distribuicao[i].larguraTotal < distribuicao[min].larguraTotal )
            min = i;
    return distribuicao[min];
}

palavras.sort(function(a,b) { return b.largura - a.largura; });
for ( var i = 0 ; i < palavras.length ; i++ ) {
    var min = minima();
    min.palavras.push(palavras[i]);
    min.larguraTotal += palavras[i].largura;
}
```

Por fim, vamos distribuir as palavras pela tela. Farei isso usando posicionamento absoluto, mas pode-se pensar em outra forma também.

```
var alturaSobrando = alturaConteiner - linhas*alturaMaxima;
var alturaAntes = alturaSobrando / linhas / 2;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < distribuicao.length ; i++ ) {
    var larguraSobrando = larguraConteiner - distribuicao[i].larguraTotal;
    var larguraAntes = larguraSobrando / distribuicao[i].palavras.length / 2;

    var top = alturaAntes + i*(2*alturaAntes + alturaMaxima);
    var left = larguraAntes;
    for ( var t = 0 ; t < distribuicao[i].palavras.length ; t++ ) {
        var palavra = distribuicao[i].palavras[t];
        $(palavra.elemento).css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: top,
            left: left
        });
        left += 2*larguraAntes + palavra.largura;
    }
}
```

[Bem homogênea, não](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/3yQEG/1/)? Agora, temos uma margem de manobra para randomizar cada palavra. Há um espaço de `larguraAntes` antes e depois de cada palavra. Idem para `alturaAntes`. Vou usar metade desse espaço (aqui você avalia o que é interessante, esteticamente falando, na minha opinião usar o espaço todo deixou a aparência meio bizarra).

```
        top: top + Math.floor(Math.random()*alturaAntes - alturaAntes/2),
        left: left + Math.floor(Math.random()*larguraAntes - larguraAntes/2)
```

[Resultado final](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/3yQEG/2/). Cada um desses passos pode ser aprimorado, se desejar, não gastei muito tempo com cada um deles não. Além disso, algumas condições limite eu creio que possam estar bugadas (por exemplo, ao testar usando o espaço todo, algumas palavras sairam fora do contêiner) - mas no exemplo acima creio que isso não ocorre.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok. Hehe vi sua pergunta, achei interessante e já fui respondendo ([*nerd sniped*...](http://xkcd.com/356/)), só depois parei pra ler com mais cuidado: "Existe algum algoritmo clássico ..." ops! Esse aí não é clássico, é *home made* mesmo... :P

Comment: Gostei! A parte do algoritmo clássico é porque eu não queria reinventar a roda, e vi a similaridade com o problema da mochila. E quanto ao *nerd sniped*: mission accomplished! :)

Comment: Tem mesmo alguma condição bugada. Vou estudar o código mais a fundo (estou implementando isto só agora).

Comment: Desculpe a falta de retorno sobre isso, estou numa correria grande de trabalho. Acabei adotando a solução do @utluiz no meu projeto, mas pretendo voltar ao assunto no futuro, para entender e testar melhor o seu código, e resolver o bug. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 5):

Me baseando no seu fiddle, resolvi tentar fazer com que as palavras se deslocassem dos seus pontos originais, aleatoriamente em qualquer ângulo, em uma distância fixa de 25px, e o resultado até que ficou bom:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JkPQ8/)

**Código:**

CSS:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var randomCoordsInACircle = function(cx, cy, radius) {
  var r2 = radius*Math.sqrt(Math.random());
  var angle = 2*Math.PI*Math.random();

  return {
    angle: angle,
    x: (r2 * Math.cos(angle) + cx),
    y: (r2 * Math.sin(angle) + cy)
  }
};

$(function () {
    $('li').each(function () {
        var rnd = randomCoordsInACircle(0,0,25);
        $(this).css({
            left: rnd.x.toFixed(0)+'px',
            top: rnd.y.toFixed(0)+'px'
        });
    });
})
```

**Referência:**

[random point within a circle, even distribution, no problem, in javascript.](http://log.the55.net/2011/11/18/random-point-within-a-circle-in-2-line-no-problem-javascript-no-less)

Comment: Interessante. Eu havia pensado em algo semelhante, mas com deslocamento aleatório em x/y sem pensar em ângulo. Mas infelizmente essa solução ainda deixa uns buracos, estou buscando algo mais harmônico.

Comment: Talvez diminuindo a distância máxima fique melhor.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Tentei com uma distância também aleatória de 0 até 30px... me diz o que você acha: http://jsfiddle.net/x79TR/

Comment: Isso aí com o texto justificado (em vez de centralizado) deu um resultado melhor! http://jsfiddle.net/fNBN4/ Obrigado!

Comment: @bfavaretto Ficou bem melhor mesmo!!! =)

Answer (score 2):

Penso que a solução mais simples é pôr todas palavras em um parágrafo em vez de uma lista, e pôr o atributo text-align em justified. Usei essa solução precisamente para mostrar uma [tag cloud com tópicos mais buscados sobre JavaScript](http://www.jsclasses.org/zeitgeist/).

```
<div style="text-align: justified; width: 20em">C C++ Java PHP JavaScript Lisp Scheme Haskell Lua Python Ruby Delphi Cobol</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu já usei algo assim numa tag cloud, mas as linhas ficam retas demais. Queria algo mais desalinhado.

Comment: Entendi. No caso eu usei tamanhos de letra diferentes porque cada palavra tinha um peso diferente. Talvez com alguns atributos de posicionamento relativo para cada palavra você pode conseguir o que pretende sem complicar demasiado.